# How to save Date & Time in Parse.com using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, parse-platform

I am trying to get the Date and Time from the user and want to submit it to Parse.com. But when I am facing the problem with the following code

What mistake am I doing here?

```
<div id="main">
 <form name="myForm" action="" method="get">
 Date: <input type="datetime-local" name="datentime" id="theDate">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction()">
</form>
```

and the javascript code

```
function myFunction()
{
    var TestObject = Parse.Object.extend("TestObject");
    var testObject = new TestObject();  
    var date = new Date();
    date = document.getElementById("theDate").value; //document.forms["myForm"]   ["datentime"].value; /*new Date();*/

    testObject.set("myDate", date);
    testObject.save(null, {
    success: function(testObject) {
        $(".success").show();
    },
    error: function(testObject, error) {
        $(".error").show();
    }
    });
}
```

In above line testObject.set("myDate", date); this like is not working.I am not sure how to take the input from the date and give it to the parse.com
where the column name is myDate of type Date
If I try testObject.set("foo","testing...") where foo is column name of type string.It's working properly

Comment: Can you include any error you're getting or be more specific as to what issue you're encountering?

Comment: @HectorRamos : testObject.set("myDate", date); this like is not working.. I am not sure how to take the input from the date and give it to the parse.com where the column name is myDate of type Date.. If I try to testObject.set("foo","testing...") where foo is column name of type string ..its working properly

Comment: have you tried using just date - not setting it to the document.getElement... Just date = new date() then set it?  If that works then you know where the issue is

Comment: @nycynik : then its working properly. I have checked that, but not sure why can't it take that value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is just with the way that you are creating a date.  I would think that it should work, but is it possible that it is creating a string object?

try checking the type of date it should show an object, if it does not, then the date is not a date, but just a string:

```
console.log(typeof(date));
```

Also try to log the value:

```
console.log(document.getElementById("theDate").value);
```

Comment: Yo thanks dude... Yes its coming in the string format ... I made the correction here it is ...var date_str = document.getElementById("theDate").value;
 var date = new Date(date_str);